# filtering within the summarise function of dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I am struggling a little with `dplyr` because I want to do two things at one and wonder if it is possible.

I want to calculate the mean of values and at the same time the mean for the values which have a specific value in an other column.

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(1234)
df <- data.frame(id=rep(1:10, each=14),
                 tp=letters[1:14],
                 value_type=sample(LETTERS[1:3], 140, replace=TRUE),
                 values=runif(140))

df %>%
  group_by(id, tp) %>%
  summarise(
    all_mean=mean(values),
    A_mean=mean(values), # Only the values with value_type A
    value_count=sum(value_type == 'A')
  )
```

So the `A_mean` column should calculate the mean of `values` where `value_count == 'A'`.

I would normally do two separate commands and merge the results later, but I guess there is a more handy way and I just don't get it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

We can try

```
 df %>%
     group_by(id, tp) %>%
     summarise(all_mean = mean(values), 
                A_mean = mean(values[value_type=="A"]),
                value_count=sum(value_type == 'A'))
```

Comment: Nice and easy solution!

Comment: WARNING: if you don't explicitly filter out NAs they'll be included because R hates you.  `A_mean = mean(values[value_type=="A" & !is.na(value_type)])`. Include this everywhere your filter variable might have NAs you don't want counted.

Comment: Or easier: `drop_na(value_type) %>%` at the top of the pipechain.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with two summary steps:

```
df %>%
  group_by(id, tp, value_type) %>%
  summarise(A_mean = mean(values)) %>%
  summarise(all_mean = mean(A_mean),
            A_mean = sum(A_mean * (value_type == "A")),
            value_count = sum(value_type == "A"))
```

The first summary calculates the means per `value_type` and the second "sums" only the mean of `value_type == "A"`

Answer (score -2):

You can also give the following function a try:

```
?summarise_if
```

(the function family is `summarise_all`)

#### Example

The [dplyr documentation](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/summarise_all.html) serves a quite good example of this, i think:

```
# The _if() variants apply a predicate function (a function that
# returns TRUE or FALSE) to determine the relevant subset of
# columns. Here we apply mean() to the numeric columns:

starwars %>%
  summarise_if(is.numeric, mean, na.rm = TRUE)

#> # A tibble: 1 x 3
#>   height  mass birth_year
#>    <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl>
#> 1   174.  97.3       87.6
```

The interesting thing here is the `predicate` function. This represents the rule by which the columns, that will have to be summarized, are selected.

Comment: Can you do an example of this?