# Calculate mean of dataset in R that satisfies two conditions

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-statements

I want to find the mean of the dataset grouped by year and book_Id in R.

I tried to use Tapply but I can only put one index condition in that function.

In SQL it would look something like

```
Select year, book_id, avg(users_read)
From
Where year = 2018 
Group by year, book_id

So my final table would like 

year  | book_id | avg(users_read)
2018.   1.         12
2018.   2.         8
2018.   3.         13
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21982987/mean-per-group-in-a-data-frame

Comment: Or another duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38094244/filtering-within-the-summarise-function-of-dplyr

Comment: Does this answer your question? [filtering within the summarise function of dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38094244/filtering-within-the-summarise-function-of-dplyr)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Translation of the SQL code in R would be -

```
res <- aggregate(users_read~year + book_id, subset(df, year == 2018), mean)
```

Or in `dplyr` -

```
library(dplyr)

res <- df %>%
  filter( year == 2018) %>%
  group_by(book_id) %>%
  summarise(users_read = mean(users_read))
```

Comment: I want to group it by each by each book id

Comment: Did you try the `aggregate` code? It groups by each book id already. Also you only have one book id here because you are filtering by it. `Where year = 2018 & book_id = 1`

Comment: yea I noticed the filter and removed it from my original post, also I just tried the aggregate code and I'm getting "no rows to aggregate" ( might be because I added the column to my table ? )

Comment: I have updated both the answer to group by `book_id`. Try the `dplyr` answer.

Comment: I got "Nan" , but there are numeric values in that column

Comment: Have you tried using `mean(users_read, na,rm = TRUE)` to remove `NA` values?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the [sqldf](/questions/tagged/sqldf) package you can use your SQL statement also in R:

```
sqldf::sqldf("
Select year, book_id, avg(users_read)
From df1
Where year = 2018 
Group by year, book_id
")
```

> ```
>   year book_id avg(users_read)
> 1 2018       1            10.4
> 2 2018       2            15.5
> 3 2018       3             9.0
> ```

#### Reproducible Data

```
set.seed(123)
n <- 20
df1 <- data.frame(year = sample(2018:2019, n, TRUE),
                  book_id = sample(3, n, TRUE),
                  users_read = sample(c(1:(n-1), NA), n))
```

Note that column `users_read` includes a `NA` value.

```
 df1
```

> ```
>    year book_id users_read
> 1  2018       1          9
> 2  2018       1         NA
> 3  2018       1         10
> 4  2019       1          7
> 5  2018       3          5
> 6  2019       2         11
> 7  2019       3          6
> 8  2019       2         19
> 9  2018       1          2
> 10 2018       2         16
> 11 2019       3          8
> 12 2019       2         12
> 13 2019       1          1
> 14 2018       3         18
> 15 2019       3          3
> 16 2018       1         17
> 17 2019       3         13
> 18 2018       2         15
> 19 2018       1         14
> 20 2018       3          4
> ```